# post xmldata through webservice iphone problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c

This is my xml

```
NSString *Message = [NSString stringWithFormat:                      
                         @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n"
                         "<query>\n"
                         "<IdCategory>1088</IdCategory>\n"
                         "</query>\n"];



NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://bvd.vndsupport.com/_ws/api/categories/index.asp"];
NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [Message length]];

[theRequest addValue: @"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[theRequest addValue: msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[theRequest setHTTPBody: [Message dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:theRequest returningResponse:nil error:nil] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@",returnString);
```

I have simply pass this category id and get the result but `returnString` always display all category details. I didn't get an exact result. Is this the correct way of passing xml data to webservice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will work perfectly. the problem is webservice page

Comment: I have an XML file with user name and password. So, it need to authenticate. How can I authenticate this xml file but username and password?

Comment: create a string format as per your xml and pass into webservice url

Comment: How to set username and password  ?, and how top connect these username name and password to the url ?

Comment: refer the link http://www.w3schools.com/soap/soap_body.asp.Pass the username & pwd as a request and get a response from an xml.

Answer (score 3):

go and search for 'wsdl2objc' it does it all for you if you wanted to do soap requests.

Comment: @Rams true, it is open source though, if you fancied you chances at making changes - I couldn't tell you anything about that though as havent bothered to look